# PyQGIS saving Raster from loop to file in QGIS3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have a huge amount of Raster Layers and I only want to change the cell size using gdal warpreproject. This is my attempt:

```
import os.path, glob

inputpath = 'C:/Users/DGM1'
outputpath = 'C:/Users/output'

directory = os.fsencode(inputpath)
os.chdir(inputpath)

for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    print(file)
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    inputname = os.path.join(os.fsdecode(directory), filename)
    outputname = outputpath + "warped" + str(filename)
    processing.run("gdal:warpreproject", 
        {'INPUT':inputname, 'SOURCE_CRS':None,
         'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:25832'),
         'RESAMPLING':0, 'NODATA':None, 'TARGET_RESOLUTION':5, 'OPTIONS':'',
         'DATA_TYPE':0, 'TARGET_EXTENT':None, 'TARGET_EXTENT_CRS':None,
         'MULTITHREADING':False, 'EXTRA':'', 'OUTPUT':outputname})
```

I don't get any mistake when running the code but there are no raster layers saved to the output.

Any idea what could be the mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change output file extension. I guess GDAL doesn't support `.txt` extension. Use for example `.XYZ`. You also miss `/` or `\\` (path separator).

Change

```
outputname = outputpath + "warped" + str(filename)
```

to

```
outputname = os.path.join(outputpath, "warped" + str(filename)[:-3] + 'XYZ')
```